# CSS shadow on SVG shape only, not entire document

Tags: css, svg, css-shapes

Is it possible to get CSS shadow on the SVG shape only, not entire document? Ie. around the blue arrow at:

```css
a:after {
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .50);
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222);
    filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222);
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(http://www.domblogger.net/buttons/play.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0;
    height: 350px;
    width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Play</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that you want the dropshadow only on the arrow shape, then don't set the background color to white (first line of your a:after stylerule).

```css
a:after {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222);
    filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #222);
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(http://www.domblogger.net/buttons/play.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0;
    height: 350px;
    width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Play</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible but you will have to apply a `filter` on the original `svg` element(`use`), not through CSS.

Change the file at http://www.domblogger.net/buttons/play.svg to:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" version="1.1">
  <defs>
    <polygon id="play" fill="rgb(0,0,200)" fill-opacity="0.6" points="0,0 0,350 300,175" />
    <filter id="d" width="120%" height="120%">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceAlpha" stdDeviation="5" />
      <feOffset dx="5" dy="5" result="offsetblur" />
      <feComponentTransfer>
        <feFuncA type="linear" slope="0.5" />
      </feComponentTransfer>
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode/>
        <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <g>
    <use filter="url(#d)" x="55" y="25" xlink:href="#play" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks. In that case I'm probably better off just adding the shadow in Adobe Flash where my SVGs are made.